# angularfire - join usernames

Tags: javascript, join, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

short question. I have a list of documents (images users has uploaded) and want to join there names. I store the uid in every imageDoc, so that can reference to the users-collection by its id.

But how can i get this?
After i have subscribed to the imageList I need something like a second loading of the names. Also it can happen, that a user uploaded multiple images and want i perform a loading of its names i would be a waste of reads if I read the previous loaded name again.

Here my code how I get the data.

```
loadImgsFromUser(uid: string) {
    const path = 'imgs';
    const colRef = collection(this.firestore, path);
    const q = query(
      colRef,
      where('cid', '==', uid),
      orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    );
    const col = collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' });
    col.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('imgsFromUserData', data);
      this.imgList = data;
      // --> now join usernames by "data.uid"
    });
}
```